# How to convert rows values in dataframe to columns labels in Python after groupby?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pivot-table, data-analysis

I have specific case where I want to convert this df:
print df

```
Schoolname  Attribute    Value  
0  xyz School  Safe         3.44  
1  xyz School  Cleanliness  2.34  
2  xyz School  Money        4.65  
3  abc School  Safe         4.40  
4  abc School  Cleanliness  4.50  
5  abc School  Money        4.90  
6  lmn School  Safe         2.34   
7  lmn School  Cleanliness  3.89  
8  lmn School  Money        4.65
```

Which i need to get in this format so that i can convert it to numpy array for linear regression modelling.

```
required_df:    
   Schoolname  Safe  Cleanliness Money  
0 xyz School   3.44   2.34       4.65   
1 abc School   4.40   4.50       4.90    
2 lmn School   2.34   3.89       4.65
```

I know we need to do groupby('Schoolname') but unable to think after that to get rows name to become column label and corresponding values reflected in required_df.

I need in this format so that I can convert it to numpy array and give it to Linear Regression model as my X vector.

Comment: Can you post your `df` so we can recreate it. That will make it easier to provide a solution. BTW: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you @JoeR for the edit.Sorry new to the forum. will take care of these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `pd.pivot`

```
In [171]: df.pivot(index='Schoolname', columns='Attribute', values='Value')
Out[171]:
Attribute   Cleanliness  Money  Safe
Schoolname
abc-School         4.50   4.90  4.40
lmn-School         3.89   4.65  2.34
xyz-School         2.34   4.65  3.44
```

or more expressible `pd.pivot_table`

```
In [172]: pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index='Schoolname', columns='Attribute')
Out[172]:
Attribute   Cleanliness  Money  Safe
Schoolname
abc-School         4.50   4.90  4.40
lmn-School         3.89   4.65  2.34
xyz-School         2.34   4.65  3.44
```